# Backbone good model structure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

I would like to know your opinion about this structure. you have 3 or 4 part in the same page. And you used a main Model to control and communication between the another Model. I'm thinking that this is a good practice to reuse de code. What do you think about it?

```
     mainModel(comunication betwen submodel)
    /    |    \
 model  model  model
```

Thank you

Comment: What you mean by mainModel? In your diagram mainModel should be a collection if you using backbone approach. Could you describe your issue more in details?

Comment: Ok, it isn't a collection. I used this to control and communication betwen the another model.

Comment: As I understand you need event aggregator. This is the best way for communication between application's parts. Look at [this](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr) lib, it might be helpful. Marionette uses it.

Comment: That is interesting, is like a global object to de communication, is it not?. I need to see if I can use in my app. Thank.

Comment: Can I used the event aggregator without Marionette?

Comment: Yes you can. Read documentation and try to build some working example.

Comment: You can extend Backbone Events and build a very lightweight version yourself: http://backbonejs.org/#Events

Comment: I have a similar problem, but a different question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172757/how-to-organize-backbone-collection-with-a-specific-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to create a mediator by extending Backbone.Events...

```
var App = {};
App.Events = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

var MainModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        App.Events.trigger("my.event");
    }
});

var ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        App.Events.on("my.event" this.onEvent, this);
    },
    onEvent: function() {}
});
var ModelB = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        App.Events.on("my.event" this.onEvent, this);
    },
    onEvent: function() {}
});
```

Comment: yes. This is the think. I don't think in extend the event. I think that is a good idea. Really nice idea. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if is a really good idea that I want to do. That is the question.

Comment: Ok. I'm feel better. ;)